# SQL "between" not inclusive

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Cases WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-01'
```

But this gives no results even though there is data on the 1st.

`created_at` looks like `2013-05-01 22:25:19`, I suspect it has to do with the time? How could this be resolved?

It works just fine if I do larger date ranges, but it should (inclusive) work with a single date too.

Comment: Well, how many numbers are between 1 and 1? Should 1.5 be between 1 and 1? [Just don't use BETWEEN for date/time ranges. Ever.](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx) And be careful how you evaluate "works just fine" - have you closely inspected the results from the last day in the range? You would only include all rows if they didn't have any time associated with them.

Comment: Updated URL for Aaron: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 387, accepted):

It *is* inclusive.  You are comparing datetimes to dates.  The second date is interpreted as midnight *when the day starts*.

One way to fix this is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cases
WHERE cast(created_at as date) BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-01'
```

Another way to fix it is with explicit binary comparisons

```
SELECT *
FROM Cases
WHERE created_at >= '2013-05-01' AND created_at < '2013-05-02'
```

Aaron Bertrand has a long blog entry on dates ([here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)), where he discusses this and other date issues.

Comment: For completeness sake on this good answer, I would suggest using `dateadd` to get the next day.

Comment: @TimLehner For the sake of a good answer, I would have used ISO-8601 format of '20130501'. For non-US people with dateformat dmy, you get this: `set dateformat dmy;select month(cast('2013-05-01' as datetime)); =1`

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - I believe the _explicit_ bit is using an interval closed at one end (`>=`) and open at the other (`<`) combined with checking one day beyond the specified end date.

Comment: This sort of problem is why I choose to represent date/times internally as Modified Julian Day numbers.  They are always with respect to UTC, in millisecond precision with just a double, and can be easily converted to displayable forms.  Moreover, date arithmetic, sorting, comparisons, and date-based filters are trivial to implement.

Comment: @scottb Personally, I would find it annoying to have to convert to datetimes every single time I wanted to display, export, import, or write a class with a datetime. I think SQL Server has plenty of built-in functionality to manipulate and compare datetimes for most purposes.

Comment: @TimLehner: of course, the choice of how to represent date/times depends on many things.  If date comparisons, arithmetic, or sorting are not an emphasis for a particular data set or application, or if you're stepping into a legacy environment which is already standardized on a particular representation then it makes sense to go with the flow.  For new app development, the advantages of representing date/times internally as universal, UTC POSIX longs or Julian Day Numbers can be compelling and well worth consideration.  This question speaks to just one issue with datetimes.

Comment: You should never cast a column in the `where` clause, since it will lose any indexing it has. It's a really bad pattern.

Comment: First one is perfect solution for dynamic date inputs.Thanks A lot.

Comment: what if the date is the last date of the month? how can I have a generic solution for every date of the year?

Comment: @Buzinas . . . You comment specifically does not apply to casting to a date in SQL Server.

Comment: @FarrukhSarmad . . . If you have a question, ask it as a question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 78):

It has been assumed that the second date reference in the `BETWEEN` syntax is magically considered to be the "end of the day" but **this is untrue**.

i.e. this was expected:

```
SELECT * FROM Cases 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN the beginning of '2013-05-01' AND the end of '2013-05-01'
```

but what really happen is this:

```
SELECT * FROM Cases 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00+00000' AND '2013-05-01 00:00:00+00000'
```

Which becomes the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM Cases WHERE created_at = '2013-05-01 00:00:00+00000'
```

---

The problem is one of perceptions/expectations about `BETWEEN` which **does** include BOTH the lower value and the upper values in the range, but **does not** magically make a date the "beginning of" or "the end of".

`BETWEEN` should be avoided when filtering by date ranges.

**Always** use the `>= AND <` instead

```
SELECT * FROM Cases 
WHERE (created_at >= '20130501' AND created_at < '20130502')
```

the parentheses are optional here but can be important in more complex queries.

Comment: Unsure about the wisdom of posting this well after the question has already been answered but I wanted to stress a slightly different point

Comment: To editors; please don't try to make the pseudo SQL into code blocks, it simply does not work as the comment relies on BOLD.

Comment: To editors (again) please, do not add spurious quotation marks through the pseudo code; they do NOT aid comprehension.

Answer (score 22):

You need to do one of these two options:

1. Include the time component in your `between` condition: `... where created_at between '2013-05-01 00:00:00' and '2013-05-01 23:59:59'` (not recommended... see the last paragraph)
2. Use inequalities instead of `between`. Notice that then you'll have to add one day to the second value: `... where (created_at >= '2013-05-01' and created_at < '2013-05-02')`

My personal preference is the second option. Also, [**Aaron Bertrand**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) has [a very clear explanation on why](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) it should be used.

Comment: +1 for 2. But -1 for 1. This end of day hack is completely unreliable and a bad idea.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I also prefer option 2 (I use it frequently). But why do you say option 1 is "completely unreliable"?

Comment: [please read this in full](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx). You should never use `BETWEEN` for date range queries that include time; way too much can go wrong.

Comment: Although 2. works I will always write it as `where ('2013-05-01' <= created_at and created_at <= '2013-05-01')`  for better readability

Answer (score 10):

Just use the time stamp as date:

```
SELECT * FROM Cases WHERE date(created_at)='2013-05-01'
```

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server, and `'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.` Need to convert http://stackoverflow.com/a/20973452/4233593

Answer (score 9):

I find that the best solution to comparing a datetime field to a date field is the following:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '5/1/2013', 
        @EndDate   DATE = '5/1/2013' 

SELECT * 
FROM   cases 
WHERE  Datediff(day, created_at, @StartDate) <= 0 
       AND Datediff(day, created_at, @EndDate) >= 0
```

This is equivalent to an inclusive between statement as it includes both the start and end date as well as those that fall between.

Answer (score 3):

```
cast(created_at as date)
```

That will work only in 2008 and newer versions of SQL Server

If you are using older version then use

```
convert(varchar, created_at, 101)
```

Comment: `convert(varchar, created_at, 101)` result is like `dd/MM/yyyy` and OP's strings are `yyyy-MM-dd`, I think this answer will not work ;).

Answer (score 3):

Even though it is inclusive, as per [Aaron Bertrand suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347649/sql-between-not-inclusive/16347680#comment23418675_16347649) ([read more about it here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common))

> don't use BETWEEN for date/time ranges.

Apart from other good answers around here, one can also use [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (to add a number of days to a given date) as follows

```
SELECT * FROM Cases WHERE created_at >= '2013-05-01' AND created_at < DATEADD(day, 1, '2013-05-01')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `date()` function which will extract the date from a datetime and give you the result as inclusive date:

```
SELECT * FROM Cases WHERE date(created_at)='2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-01'
```

Answer (score 2):

your code

```
SELECT * FROM Cases WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-01'
```

how SQL reading it

```
SELECT * FROM Cases WHERE '2013-05-01 22:25:19' BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-05-01 00:00:00'
```

if you don't mention time while comparing DateTime and Date by default hours:minutes:seconds will be zero in your case dates are the same but if you compare time `created_at` is `22 hours` ahead from your end date range

if the above is clear you fix this in many ways like putting  ending hours in your end date eg `BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND ''2013-05-01 23:59:59''`

OR

simply cast create_at as date like `cast(created_at as date)` after casting as date `'2013-05-01 22:25:19'` will be equal to `'2013-05-01 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

**Dyamic date BETWEEN sql query**

```
var startDate = '2019-08-22';
var Enddate = '2019-10-22'
     let sql = "SELECT * FROM Cases WHERE created_at BETWEEN '?' AND '?'";
     const users = await mysql.query( sql, [startDate, Enddate]);
```