# select record in mysql between time

Tags: mysql

How to make query in mysql when I have table Manage :

```
number=1 , name=tanti, timeIn=07:00:00,timeOut=09:00:00
```

I want Select name and time in my pc is 08:00:00 but I want still get "tanti" because 08:00:00 > timeIn and 08:00:00 < timeOut. Help me pleaseeee

Comment: `select ... where '08:00:00' BETWEEN timeIn and timeOut`

Comment: Try searching for an answer to your question before posting... ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's just like you wrote in your question:

```
SELECT name
FROM Manage
WHERE '08:00:00' > timeIn AND '08:00:00' < timeOut
```

You can also shorten it using `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT name
FROM Manage
WHERE '08:00:00' BETWEEN timeIn AND timeOut
```

Comment: Almost, except that [BETWEEN is inclusive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347649/sql-between-not-inclusive) ...

Comment: Good point. Although it's not obvious that he really wants exclusive (even though that's what he wrote -- most people don't really think about it).