# Problem with a query in Postgres that I want to move to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in postgres that I now need to run on SQL Server. Obviously I have already changed the trunc per round and basic things, but mainly I have a problem in the principle select distinct on (c.cod_socio) tbl. * Since SQL Server does not recognize that syntax.

```
select distinct on (c.cod_socio) 
    tbl.*, h.cod_oficina, h.cod_transaccion, h.num_transaccion, 
    h.num_sec, h.fec_movimiento
from 
    sgf_det_mov_his h 
inner join 
    sgf_cuenta c on c.cod_producto = h.cod_producto and c.cod_cuenta = h.cod_cuenta
inner join 
    sgf_tran t on t.cod_transaccion = h.cod_transaccion and t.cod_oficina = h.cod_oficina and t.cod_tipo_transaccion in ('DA', 'DP','NC') 
inner join 
    (select 
         sgf_cuenta.cod_socio, 
         sum(trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_efectivo, 0) + trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_cheques, 0)) as total 
     from 
         sgf_det_mov_his, sgf_cuenta, sgf_tran
     where 
         sgf_cuenta.cod_producto = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_producto
         and sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_cuenta
         and sgf_det_mov_his.sts_mov = 'A'
         and sgf_tran.cod_transaccion = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_transaccion
         and sgf_tran.cod_oficina = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_oficina
         and sgf_cuenta.cod_producto <> 2
         and sgf_tran.cod_tipo_transaccion in ('DA', 'DP','NC')
         and isnull(sgf_tran.cod_uaf, 0) > 0 
         and isnull(sgf_tran.cod_uaf, 0) not in (71)
         and sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta not in (select cod_cuenta 
                                           from sgf_credito 
                                           where sgf_credito.cod_producto = sgf_cuenta.cod_producto
                                             and sgf_credito.cod_cuenta = sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta
                                             and sts_operacion in ('A'))
         and date(sgf_det_mov_his.fec_movimiento) between '2015-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
     group by 
         sgf_cuenta.cod_socio
     having 
         sum(trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_efectivo,0) + trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_cheques,0)) >= 5000) tbl on tbl.cod_socio = c.cod_socio
where 
    date(h.fec_movimiento) between '2015-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
order by 
    c.cod_socio, h.fec_movimiento desc
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`distinct on (...)` simply retains the "first row" which may be emulated using `row_number() over(...)` and a following `where clause` predicate that limits to one row per partition.. Note that `distinct on` relies on the `order by` clause to decide the "first row", so you need the equivalent conditions in the `over clause`. Also note if you after greater query compatibility between the two databases you could use the same row_number approach in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.cod_socio ORDER BY h.fec_movimiento DESC) AS rn
      , c.cod_socio
      , tbl.*
      , h.cod_oficina
      , h.cod_transaccion
      , h.num_transaccion
      , h.num_sec
      , h.fec_movimiento
    FROM sgf_det_mov_his h
    INNER JOIN sgf_cuenta c ON c.cod_producto = h.cod_producto
        AND c.cod_cuenta = h.cod_cuenta
    INNER JOIN sgf_tran t ON t.cod_transaccion = h.cod_transaccion
        AND t.cod_oficina = h.cod_oficina
        AND t.cod_tipo_transaccion IN ('DA', 'DP', 'NC')
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            sgf_cuenta.cod_socio
          , SUM(trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_efectivo, 0) + trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_cheques, 0)) AS total
        FROM sgf_det_mov_his
           , sgf_cuenta
           , sgf_tran
        WHERE sgf_cuenta.cod_producto = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_producto
        AND sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_cuenta
        AND sgf_det_mov_his.sts_mov = 'A'
        AND sgf_tran.cod_transaccion = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_transaccion
        AND sgf_tran.cod_oficina = sgf_det_mov_his.cod_oficina
        AND sgf_cuenta.cod_producto <> 2
        AND sgf_tran.cod_tipo_transaccion IN ('DA', 'DP', 'NC')
        AND ISNULL(sgf_tran.cod_uaf, 0) > 0
        AND ISNULL(sgf_tran.cod_uaf, 0) NOT IN (71)
        AND sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta NOT IN (
            SELECT
                cod_cuenta
            FROM sgf_credito
            WHERE sgf_credito.cod_producto = sgf_cuenta.cod_producto
            AND sgf_credito.cod_cuenta = sgf_cuenta.cod_cuenta
            AND sts_operacion IN ('A')
        )
        AND DATE(sgf_det_mov_his.fec_movimiento) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2019-01-01'
        GROUP BY
            sgf_cuenta.cod_socio
        HAVING SUM(trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_efectivo, 0) + trunc(sgf_det_mov_his.val_cheques, 0)) >= 5000
    ) tbl ON tbl.cod_socio = c.cod_socio
    WHERE DATE(h.fec_movimiento) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2019-01-01'
) AS d
WHERE d.rn = 1
ORDER BY
    d.cod_socio
  , d.fec_movimiento DESC
```

Comment: Just as an aside, I really suggest you **do not use** `DATE(..)` in the where clause for your date range please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25564544/2067753 and you probably should not use `between` for your date range either , see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190806/2067753