# WhereBetween dates with cast in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Recently I've used **whereBetween** to get the date range of both dates but the result is not inclusive in same date. So I come out with this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE cast(created_at as date) BETWEEN '2019-07-21' AND '2019-07-21'
```

Now, since I'm just new in laravel. How can I adopt this query to laravel?

Here is my code in laravel:

```
$student = $this->student
->whereBetween('created_at', ['2019-07-21', '2019-07-21'])
->select('*')
->get()
```

I dont know how to add cast in whereBetween. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you show us sample data from the `created_at` column?  Are you storing your dates as _text_?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes ```created_at``` data type is ```datetime```

Comment: Then there is no reason why my answer should not be working.

Comment: What I want is to get the data within the same date. Try run your query with the same date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest avoiding using the my MySQL CAST() construct and insted include the edge times in both dates. The query will perform better as well.

```
$student = $this->student
->whereBetween('created_at', ["$from 00:00:00", "$to 23:59:59"])
// If working with Carbon instances
// ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $to->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59'])
->select('*')
->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may actually phrase your current query using date literals, and completely avoid the cast to date:

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE created_at >= '2019-07-21' AND created_at < '2019-07-22'
```

Laravel code:

```
$student = $this->student
    ->where('created_at', '>=', '2019-07-21')
    ->where('created_at', '<', '2019-07-22')
    ->select('*')
    ->get();
```

Note that this approach leaves the `WHERE` clause *sargable*, meaning that an index on the `created_at` column can be used.

Comment: Your laravel code is the same thought as my laravel code. Nothing works

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347649/sql-between-not-inclusive/16347680#16347680).

Comment: My answer is certainly not the same as your code, and it should work assuming that `created_at` is a `datetime` column.

Answer (score 1):

Easy Solution

```
$student = $this->student
->whereBetween(DB::raw('date(created_at)'), ['2019-07-21', '2019-07-21'])
->select('*')
->get()
```